# IIS AD Permissions

Tags: iis, permissions

We need the ability to run a script to restart the app pool of the specific IIS 7 site (Windows 2008) from a Windows 10 machine.

We have a script, however, we need to use a service account to run the script.

We have tested the script with a domain admin account and this is successful (Right click and run as different user), however, we would like to avoid using a domain admin account for this.

We have tried the following:
Grant the service account IIS_IUSRS permissions.
Grant local admin permissions on the IIS server.
Granted full permissions within the specific IIS site.

In short: We need to give a service account the lowest permissions in order to restart an IIS app pool remotely.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you grant him in the local admin group of the server ?

Comment: What error you get in script/console output or in windows event log?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the use of a domain account to run services is no-brainer so that's a good starting point. Adding the service account IIS_IUSRS to the server administrators group would be enough for the script to be executed. have you already tested/confirmed the functionality?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to say "avoiding the use of a Domain _Admin_ account to run services," not "avoiding the use of a domain account?"

Comment: @RobbieCrash Yes, I missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out.